# check if any element contains certain css style

Tags: jquery

I am wondering to find out the checking process for an element to contain any css style.

I do have below html code:

```
<ul id="sample">
    <li style="left:-100px">text 1</li>
    <li style="left:0px">text 2</li>
    <li style="left:100px">text 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to find out the "li" whose style left is 0px and then want to apply any more style to that li.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#sample li").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('left') == "0px";
}).css('color', 'blue');
```

Comment: can you please give me the overview of filter method please? :)

Answer (score 7):

```
$('ul#sample li').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('left') == '0'){
        $(this).css('background','red');
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dnqf8/3/

You could also do this with plain JS.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if(a[i].style.left == '0px'){
        a[i].style.background = 'red';
    }
}
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dnqf8/2/

Comment: Thanks @Kieran.  I liked you edits, btw, but I had to overwrite them to add the second plain JS solution. ;-)