# Using jquery, set variable to the object with a certain css property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of LIs that get moved around the page. I want to be able to set a variable to whatever LI has a css property "left: 0px" (there will only be one).

I can't seem to figure out how to narrow down a list this way, every method I find just wants to add that property.

So to put it in a more verbose way:

```
var my_var = $('ul#slider li') with the property "left: 0px"
```

and it should return something like:

```
<li><img src="image1.jpg"></li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's setting the "left: 0px"? I ask b/c a common way to locate a node is by a class. Can you have the code that sets this style also assign a class or id to it? Then finding it would be trivial.

Comment: Why not have the code that moves the LIs also set the variable whenever it sets something's `left` css property to 0px?

Comment: You don't need to mess with setting special classes if you're using jQuery -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

related issue here: [check if any element contains certain css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495015/check-if-any-element-contains-certain-css-style) using filter is the best bet.

or you may want to take the "classes" approach and see here: [jQuery: check if element has CSS attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239567/jquery-check-if-element-has-css-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jQuery, without needing to mess with assigning special classes. You will want to use jQuery's [.filter( function(index) )](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var my_element = $('ul#slider li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('left', '0px').length > 0;
});
```

jQuery's filter method accepts, among other things, a function that can return a [truthy or falsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) value that controls whether to filter items in the set. So we can use the filter method to check each `li`'s css with jQuery's [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method, returning `true` if it fits your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css class.
Here's an example:

CSS :

```
.left {left: 50px;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li id="li1">Left = 0px</li>
<li id="li2" class="left">Left = 50px</li>
</ul>
```

to get the li1 (the one without left class / styling):

```
var my_var = $('li:not([left])');
```

Good luck!